# Затупок со swiper слайдером

Tags: slider, swiper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте, не могу понять как добавить цифру в swiper слайдере как добавить цифру внутрь кружка active какой скрипт добавить обьясните

Comment: цифру активного слайдера то есть если ты просмтриваешь первый слайдер то цифра 01 если третий то 03

Comment: ответьте( пожалуйста, кто-нибудь((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение, если я правильно понял вам нужно именно это:

```js
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
          return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
        },
      },
    });
```

```css
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      height: 300px;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .swiper-pagination-bullet {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 20px;
      font-size: 12px;
      color:#000;
      opacity: 1;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
      color:#fff;
      background: #007aff;
    }
    .swiper-pagination-bullet{
      height: 20px !important;
      width: 20px !important;
    }
```

```html
  

  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```